# Finding the sum of a series by $V_n$ method

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let the sum of the series $$\frac{1}{1^3} + \frac{1+2}{1^3+2^3} +\frac{1+2+3}{1^3+2^3+3^3} + \cdots + \dfrac{1+2+\cdots+n}{1^3+2^3+\cdots+n^3}$$ be $S_n$. Find the value of $S_n$.

I want to learn how to solve this problem using $V_n$ method. And do I have to seperate the numerator and denominator into different series?. Please help

Comment: What is the Vn method?

Comment: It is a long method which has a long proofbut it is useful to solve these kinds of problem. You can google it

Comment: I guess $1$st step can be to apply formula $$1^3+2^3+\ldots+k^3=(1+2+\ldots+k)^2,$$ then the term of the series will have easier form: $$\dfrac{1+2+\ldots+k}{1^3+2^3+\ldots+k^3}=\dfrac{1}{1+2+\ldots+k}.$$

Comment: ... then rewrite $\dfrac{1}{1+2+\ldots+k}$ as $\dfrac{2}{k(k+1)}$, and then as $\dfrac{2}{k}-\dfrac{2}{k+1}$. After that telescope the series. But I'm not sure this  is Vn method or no.

Comment: I call that the method of telescoping series.

Comment: Yes I just need the series  in the fractional form with numerator as 1. Then I can do it myself. Seems like you are going in the right way. Can you please elaborate what you have done in an answer

Comment: Ok, in few minutes.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvinience Bernard I was not aware of that name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we can apply [Power Sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerSum.html) formula or  [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) to rewrite sum of cubes in the form
$$
1^3+2^3+\ldots+k^3=(1+2+\ldots+k)^2=\left(\dfrac{k(k+1)}{2}\right)^2.
$$
Then the term of the series will have easier form:
$$
\dfrac{1+2+\ldots+k}{1^3+2^3+\ldots+k^3}=\dfrac{1}{1+2+\ldots+k}=\dfrac{2}{k(k+1)}.
$$

When we rewrite the fraction $\dfrac{2}{k(k+1)}$ as difference of fractions:
$$
\dfrac{2}{k(k+1)} = \dfrac{2}{k} - \dfrac{2}{k+1},
$$
we can apply [Telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) to find final answer.

---

Series then will get the form:
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
\left(\dfrac{2}{1}\right. & - \left.\dfrac{2}{2}\right) + &  & & & & \\ 
& \left(\dfrac{2}{2} \right.& - \left.\dfrac{2}{3}\right) + & & & & \\
& & \left(\dfrac{2}{3} \right.&- \left.\dfrac{2}{4}\right) + & & &\\
& & & \ldots + & & \\
& & & & \left(\dfrac{2}{k-1} \right.& - \left.\dfrac{2}{k}\right) + & \\
& & & & & \left(\dfrac{2}{k} \right.& - \left.\dfrac{2}{k+1}\right) + \\
& & & & & & \ldots + \\
& & & & & & & \left(\dfrac{2}{n} \right.& - \left.\dfrac{2}{n+1}\right) .
\end{array}

Answer (score 0):

notice that what you have here is:
$$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\sum_{k=1}^ik}{\sum_{j=1}^ij^3}$$
now, it is well-known that:
$$\sum_{k=1}^ik=\frac{i(i+1)}{2}$$
$$\sum_{j=1}^ij^3=\frac{i^2(i+1)^2}{4}$$
and so we can see that:
$$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^ik}{\sum_{j=1}^ij^3}=\frac{2}{i(i+1)}$$
and so we can now say:
$$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{2}{i(i+1)}=2\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac1i-\frac1{i+1}\right)$$
Now notice that this is a [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)